# RadGridView GridViewSelectColumn even when disabled still selectable

Tags: wpf, silverlight, gridview, telerik, radgridview

I am using a Telerik Gridview to give the option of selecting all to users.
I am using styles to make a few checkboxes disable which works fine. But, still users can select the disabled by clicking on the disabled check box or by selecting all.
Anyone can help?
 Thanks in advance

```
<TelerikGridView:RadGridView  
                  Name="dataGridView" 
                  Height="485"
                  Grid.Row="0"                                    
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  IsReadOnly="False"
                  IsFilteringAllowed="True"
                  CanUserInsertRows="False"
                  SelectionMode="Multiple"                                    
                  CanUserSelect="True"
                  CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                  AlternationCount="2" >

<TelerikGridView:RadGridView.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyle" TargetType="CheckBox">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsReady}"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="{Binding IsReady}"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsReady,Mode=OneWay}"></Setter>
    </Style>
</TelerikGridView:RadGridView.Resources>

<TelerikGridView:RadGridView.Columns>

    <TelerikGridView:GridViewSelectColumn CheckBoxStyle="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyle}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReady}"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is said in documentation (https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/columns/columntypes/column-types-select-column)

> it allows you to select a given row via a checkbox, in other words - each CheckBox's IsChecked property is bound to the IsSelected property of the corresponding row.

means, it doesn't really matter if you disable/enable it - when you are selecting row, checkbox is being selected. You might be looking for CheckBox Column (https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/columns/columntypes/checkbox-column)

or maybe DataColumn with checkbox template, as follows:

```
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding MyData, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"                                      
                                       />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Best Regards,

Mateusz